# React Native this.state.questions.map() is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

It's my understanding that the most common use care for iterating over a list of data is `map`, which is an array method that iterates over an array, but when I tried to apply it here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class QuestionList extends Component {
  state = { questions: [] };

  componentWillMount() {
    axios
      .get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&difficulty=hard&type=boolean')
      .then(response => this.setState({ questions: response.data }));
  }

  // renderQuestions() {
  //   return this.state.questions.map(question => <Text>{}</Text>);
  // }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default QuestionList;
```

I ended up getting an error in the Simulator saying that `this.state.questions.map()` is not a function. I have searched for similar errors online, but they do not apply to my use case.

Keep in mind I commented out the code and erased what I had inside of `<Text>` because my machine was about to take off.

I don't know what this error means short of not being able to use the `map()` array helper method, does that mean I need to be applying a different helper method to iterate through this list of questions?

I did a console log of the response object like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class QuestionList extends Component {
  state = { questions: [] };

  componentWillMount() {
    axios
      .get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&difficulty=hard&type=boolean')
      .then(response => console.log(response));
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default QuestionList;
```

and I got back the response object in the console:
[image]

from axios with a status of 200 which means  the request was successful. You will notice I also go the data property and inside that is the results property and then the category with questions is inside of it:

[image]

So I am wondering if its that `results` property that I need to also implmement, but when I tried it I would get `map()` undefined.

Comment: Make sure `response.data` is an array. Try to log the value on console to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API returns an object, which has no `map` method.

`response.data.results` is an array so change it to that if you intend to map over it:

```
this.setState({ questions: response.data.results }))
```

It's advisable to use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` for async update.